# notification-menu: Wrap long text of notification

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using [this plug-in](http://www.codebasehero.com/files/notification-menu/demo/)  to display notification for my web app.

Can Someone guide me, how can I display long notification message[image]

Refer Snapshot: If I do enter long message,its not displayed properly.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

On your css (style_light.css line 240) comment these two lines:

```
.notification-list-item .message {
   display: block;
   margin-right: 22px;
   /* white-space: nowrap; */
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
```

}

Aaaand, on the same CSS line 204 comment the height of this class

```
.notification-list-item {
  color: #666;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /* height: 16px; */
}
```